# Converting FLV to SWF to play on Web

Tags: flash, flv, flvplayback, adobe-premiere

I want a little greeter guy on my website. I have received a .mov from Adobe Premiere with a transparent background. I opened this in Adobe After Effects, went to composition->add to render queue, I set the output format to FLV with RGB+Alpha and Audio included. I then uploaded the FLV to my webserver, opened the FLV from my server into Flash Professional, chose a FLVPlayBack Skin and selected the "already deployed" option for the source of my file. I then File->Export to a .swf and upload the .swf back to my server. When I embed this into my home page, the guy does not load all the way, I get about 5 seconds worth. The SWF is around 50 KB and the FLV is around 18,000 KB. The video is 1 minute 15 seconds long.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you convert video in swf formate you cannot reduce more.. you told that video duration is 75 seconds. you have to use adobe media encoder to compress the video as flv or mp4, it should make your video below 2 mb based on your dimension of video ,   pls mention your video dimension(width and height of the video).

thanks 
Jasil

Comment: its 200 px wide by 400 px height

Answer (score 1):

you can download a aneesoft video converter on the internet to convert flv to swf.
i also don't know what happend,but you can have a try!
good luck for you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a software convert flv to swf then update on web, I know FLV to Video Converter Pro 2 can convert flv to swf, maybe you can try it, http://www.flvsoft.com/flv_to_video/
good luck!